# Prepaid/Postpaid SIM card that is not throttled for Skype/WhatsApp in Germany

Tags: germany, cellphones, data-plans, roaming

I am looking for companies that offer prepaid/postpaid SIM card with good data plans that I can use with my phone to make WhatsApp/Skype audio/video calls.

I have read that some providers throttle calls under a data plan.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49910/discussion-on-question-by-krish-prepaid-postpaid-sim-card-that-is-not-throttled).

Answer (score 1):

German telecom providers usually don't have very good data plans. I can suggest [Premium Sim](https://www.premiumsim.de/) as a cheap option. 10 Eur/month for 1 GB LTE (not always LTE but yeah) or 25 Eur/month for 5 GB. (Both connections without a contract, so you're billed monthly and can cancel your connection anytime). You will also get unlimited free calls to all networks in Germany. Haven't heard of throttling here in Germany.

Answer (score -1):

You can check http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Germany
Their information, in general, always correct.